# mongodb retrieve one field from every document into array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to get one field from the selected documents but I want all of the values to be in a simple array.

```
users.find({}, ['regid'], function(err, docs){
    //console.log(docs);
});
```

should return:

```
['reg1','reg2',...]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
users.find({}, {'regid' : 1}).toArray(function(err, docs){
    //console.log(docs);
});
```